# Correct rotation with Quaternion

Tags: xna, c#, 3d, rotation, quaternion

I have some problems with a rotating marble.
I've tried it with `Matrix.CreateFromYawPitchRoll` and `Matrix.CreateRotation` but there were some problems, I think it's due to the *Gimbal lock* effect.

So, I've tried using **quaternions** instead, but nothing changed.
When moving on only an axis it works fine, but when the rotation occurs on two different axes the marble still rotates on wrong axes.

Here's my code:

```cs
// declarations
Vector3 Position = Vector3.Zero;
Vector3 Rotation = Vector3.Zero;
Quaternion qRotation = Quaternion.Identity;

AbsoluteBoneTransforms = new Matrix[Model.Bones.Count]; 
            Model.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(AbsoluteBoneTransforms);
```

In the `Update` method:

```cs
Position += speed;
Rotation = speed * MathHelper.ToRadians(-1.5f);

Quaternion rot = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Right, Rotation.Z) *
                Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Backward, Rotation.X);

qRotation *= rot;
```

And in the `Draw` method:

```cs
effect.World = AbsoluteBoneTransforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] * 
  Matrix.CreateFromQuaternion(qRotation) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(Position);
```

What's wrong?

**EDIT**

I've tried calculating directly the axis of rotation of my marble, instead of using combination of multiple axes:

```
angle += speed.Length() * angularVelocity;
qRotation = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Cross(speed, Vector3.Up), angle);
qRotation.Normalize();
```

`angle` is a float that keeps track of the current movement.
This solution doesn't seem to create *Gimbal lock*, but marble rotations aren't correct, it seems that the rotating speed is not constant, but became faster and slower over time, I can't understand why.

Comment: I'm gonna have to throw a remark at you: quaternion operations can also easily lead to gimbal lock! See this for an explanation http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/180183-Quaternion-based-camera-still-has-gimbal-lock . However, a gimbal lock occurs if and only if one axis moves rigidly with another (i.e. you really have a gimbal-like joint hierarchy). Your problem surely comes from how you compute your `rot` quaternion. To solve it, try and directly compute the axis of rotation and the angle, instead of composing two rotations... and `rotates on wrong axes` = *in what way*?

Comment: I've tried to compute directly the axis of rotation like this:
`Vector3 axis = Vector3.Cross(speed, Vector3.Up);`
but the rotation is still wrong.
"Rotates on wrong axes" means that if I rotate on X and Z both it seems that my rotation involves Y, too.

Comment: related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23238/simplest-way-of-making-a-sphere-roll-in-a-realistic-way/30102#30102

Comment: I've corrected a mistake (not updating the quaternion) and I've added a few remarks you should really consider to achieve a more synchronized effect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't know any XNA, this might help you "cheat" your way into achieving that rolling effect of the marble:

```
Position += speed;

angle = Magnitude(speed) * MathHelper.ToRadians(-1.5f);

Quaternion rot = Quaternion.CreateFromAxisAngle(Vector3.Cross(speed, Vector3.UP), angle);

qRotation *= rot;
```

So, instead of multiplying quaternions and achieving a chaotic wobbly effect, you should only update the angular position and use that to achieve the rolling effect.

**Later edit**:

What happens when your sphere moves from position *A* to position *B*:

- the speed is used to translate it (you should consider adding a *deltaTime* to make it more FPS independent)
- you know how much the ball moves: |AB| = |speed| (for your particular case) so you can determine how much it has rolled/rotated around the `cross(speed, up)` vector/axis. This amount is the angle `|AB|/(2*pi*radius)` - you should incorporate the marble radius to achieve believable roll with no sliding/slippage
- lastly, `qRotation` is updated to reflect the sphere's current rotation w.r.t. to its starting pose

Of course, the correct way to achieve rolling behaviour from a physically accurate POV is to use the [inertia tensor](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/aeronautics-and-astronautics/16-07-dynamics-fall-2009/lecture-notes/MIT16_07F09_Lec26.pdf).

I implemented a short OpenGL demo using the following snippet to update the rolling sphere (and it worked):

```
  double radius = 0.1;
  static Quaternion qRot = identityq<double>();
  static double dTime = 0.002;

  Position += Velocity * dTime;
  double angle = length(Velocity) / radius * dTime;
  Vector3 axis = cross(Vector3(0,0,1), Velocity);
  normalize(axis);

  qRot = quat_from_axis_angle<double>(axis, angle) * qRot;
```

Comment: I've already tried something like this, but maybe I'm doing something wrong. Your answer seems the right way, I'll try.

Comment: I'll update my question with what I did now.

Comment: I don't know why, but only if I overwrite `qRotation` (instead of multiplying `qRotation *= rot`) the *Gimbal lock* effect disappears.

Comment: That's really not gimbal lock. I forgot to modify the `angle` computation :(.. sorry. You're not supposed to accumulate angle offsets like in my initial code, you must directly use them to update the quaternion. The quaternion update will accumulate the correct rotation offset.

Comment: Ok, that's clear, anyway if I update the quaternion the resultant rotation still occurs on wrong axes :(

Comment: Yeah, I've already found the problem, and as you wrote too, the order of the quaternion multiplication was wrong. The correct one is `qRotation = rot * qRotation;`